# dxDataGrid keep firing event onEditorPrepared non-stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, lookup, dx-data-grid

I'm working on DevExtreme's dxDataGrid using jQuery and Javascript.

In my datagrid, there are 2 main columns: `expense_code` and `item_id`. These two columns are cascading lookups. `expense_code` is like a group of items so it should be selected first to filter items in `item_id` column. The data for both lookup columns derive from master tables `ExpenseCode` and `ItemMaster` respectively.

These two columns are now working fine. The problem is that, after item in `item_id` is selected, the detail of selected item should be fill in other columns (for example, `item_unit_name`). In my code, I tried to set grid data in [onEditorPrepared](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxDataGrid/Configuration/#onEditorPrepared) event using [cellValue](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxDataGrid/Methods/#cellValuerowIndex_dataField_value) function. However, after I tried to select item, it trigger this event non-stop for some reason. Here is my code:

```
$('#grid_Item').dxDataGrid({
    dataSource: orderItemStore,
    editing: {
        mode: 'batch',
        newRowPosition: 'last',
        allowUpdating: true,
        allowDeleting: true,
        allowAdding: true,
    },
    columns: [{
        caption: 'No',
        width: 40,
        cellTemplate(cell, info) {
            cell.text(info.row.rowIndex + 1);
        },
    }, {
        caption: 'Expense Code',
        dataField: 'expense_code',
        width: 120,
        cellTemplate(cell, info) {
            cell.text(info.data.expense_code);
        },
        lookup: {
            dataSource: {
                paginate: true,
                pageSize: 10,
                store: expenseCodeStore,
            },
            valueExpr: "expense_code",
            displayExpr(item) {
                return `${item.expense_code} : ${item.expense_name}`;
            },
            allowClearing: true,
        },
        editorOptions: {
            dropDownOptions: {
                minWidth: 300,
            },
        },
        validationRules: [{ type: "required" }]
    }, {
        caption: 'Material',
        dataField: 'item_id',
        lookup: {
            dataSource(options) {
                let selectedExpenseCode = options?.data?.expense_code;

                console.log({ selectedExpenseCode });   //this line seems working properly

                return {
                    paginate: true,
                    pageSize: 10,
                    store: new DevExpress.data.CustomStore({
                        key: 'item_id',
                        loadMode: 'raw',
                        load() {
                            return $.getJSON('?handler=ItemMasters', { expenseCode: selectedExpenseCode });
                        },
                        byKey(key) {
                            return $.getJSON('?handler=ItemMaster', { itemId: key });
                        },
                    }),
                };
            },
            valueExpr: "item_id",
            displayExpr: "item_name",
            allowClearing: true,
        },
        validationRules: [{ type: "required" }]
    }, {
        ...
    }, {
        caption: 'Unit',
        dataField: 'item_unit_name',
        width: 80,
        validationRules: [{ type: "required" }],
    }, {
        ...
    }],
    onEditorPrepared(e) {
        if (e.dataField == "item_id") {
            $(e.editorElement).dxSelectBox("instance").on("selectionChanged", function (args) {

                console.log(`setting unit name...`)

                var grid = $("#grid_Item").dxDataGrid("instance");
                var index = e.row.rowIndex;
                var result = args.selectedItem.item_unit_name;
                grid.cellValue(index, "item_unit_name", result);    //this line cause infinite event looping
            });
        }
    },
    ...
    remoteOperations: false,
    showBorders: true,
});
```

When the event is looping, the console will have two logs from `datasource` of item lookup and `onEditorPrepared` event repeating infinitely.